# What else can `loeb` function be used for?

Tags: haskell, functor, curry-howard

I am trying to understand ["Löb and möb: strange loops in Haskell"](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/loeb-moeb.md), but right now the meaning is sleaping away from me, I just don't see why it could be useful. Just to recall function `loeb` is defined as

```
loeb :: Functor f => f (f a -> a) -> f a
loeb x = go where go = fmap ($ go) x
```

or equivalently:

```
loeb x = go 
  where go = fmap (\z -> z go) x
```

In the article there is an example with `[]` functor and spreadsheets implementation, but it is bit foreign for me just as spreadsheets themselves (never used them).

While I'm understanding that spreadsheet thing, I think it would help a lot for me and others to have more examples, despite lists. Is there any application for `loeb` for `Maybe` or other functors?

Comment: When you try usig 'loeb' using 'Maybe', you will find only two trivial  ways to do it.  Or you could try and define the Fibonacci series, [Integer]...

Comment: If the functor is also applicative, then by interchange law `loeb g = x where x = g <*> pure x`. Reminds us of `fix f = x where x = f $ x`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The primary source (I think) for `loeb` is [Dan Piponi's blog, *A Neighborhood of Infinity*](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/11/from-l-theorem-to-spreadsheet.html). There he explains the whole concept in greater detail. I'll replicate a little bit of that as an answer and add some examples.

`loeb` implements a strange kind of lazy recursion

```
loeb :: Functor a => a (a x -> x) -> a x
loeb x = fmap (\a -> a (loeb x)) x
```

Let's imagine we have a type `a`, where `Functor a`, and an `a`-algebra (a function of type `a x -> x`). You might think of this as a way of computing a value from a structure of values. For instance, here are a few `[]`-algebras:

```
length                ::          [Int] -> Int
(!! 3)                ::          [a]   -> a
const 3               :: Num a => [a]   -> a
\l -> l !! 2 + l !! 3 :: Num a => [a]   -> a
```

We can see that these `a`-algebras can use both values stored in the `Functor` and the structure of the `Functor` itself.

Another way to think of `d :: a x -> x` is as a value of `x` which requires some context–a whole `Functor`ized value `a x`–in order to be computed. Perhaps this interpretation is more clearly written as `Reader (a x) x`, emphasizing that this is just a value of `x` which is delayed, awaiting the `a x` context to be produced.

```
type Delay q x = q -> x
```

Using these ideas we can describe `loeb` as follows. We're given a `f`-structure containing some `Delay`ed values, where `f` is a `Functor`

```
Functor f, f (Delay q x)
```

Naturally, if we were given a `q` then we could convert this into a not delayed form. In fact, there's only one (non-cheating) function that does this polymorphically:

```
force :: Functor f => f (Delay q x) -> q -> f x
force f q = fmap ($ q) f
```

What `loeb` does is handle the extra tricky case where `q` is actually `force f q`, the very result of this function. If you're familiar with `fix`, this is exactly how we can produce this result.

```
loeb :: Functor a => a (Delay (a x) x) -> a x
loeb f = fix (force f)
```

---

So to make an example, we simply must build a structure containing `Delay`ed values. One natural example of this is to use the list examples from before

```
> loeb [ length                  :: [Int] -> Int
       , const 3                 :: [Int] -> Int
       , const 5                 :: [Int] -> Int
       , (!! 2)                  :: [Int] -> Int
       , (\l -> l !! 2 + l !! 3) :: [Int] -> Int
       ]
[5, 3, 5, 5, 10]
```

Here we can see that the list is full of values delayed waiting on the result of evaluating the list. This computation can proceed exactly because there are no loops in data dependency, so the whole thing can just be determined lazily. For instance, `const 3` and `const 5` are both immediately available as values. `length` requires that we know the length of the list but none of the values contained so it also proceeds immediately on our fixed-length list. The interesting ones are the values delayed waiting on other values from inside our result list, but since `(!! 2)` only ends up depending on the third value of the result list, which is determined by `const 5` and thus can be immediately available, the computation moves forward. The same idea happens with `(\l -> l !! 2 + l !! 3)`.

---

So there you have it: `loeb` completes this strange kind of delayed value recursion. We can use it on any kind of `Functor`, though. All we need to do is to think of some useful `Delay`ed values.

---

Chris Kuklewicz's comment notes that there's not a lot you could do interestingly with `Maybe` as your functor. That's because all of the delayed values over `Maybe` take the form

```
maybe (default :: a) (f :: a -> a) :: Maybe a -> a
```

and all of the interesting values of `Maybe (Delay (Maybe a) a)` ought to be `Just (maybe default f)` since `loeb Nothing = Nothing`. So at the end of the day, the `default` value never even gets used---we always just have that

```
loeb (Just (maybe default f)) == fix f
```

so we may as well write that directly.

Comment: The `Maybe a -> a` is an interesting *default-value*-algebra and is isomorphic to the [difference semigroup](https://github.com/arkeet/difference/blob/0f0e14f51cf1ecd7ebf2d8c52204bd91ae3b2969/src/Data/Semigroup/Difference.hs) `data Diff a = Diff (a -> a) a` going from `\(Diff a' a) -> maybe a a'` to `\f -> Diff (f . Just) (f Nothing)` used to implement folds over non-empty lists.. I don't know if it's useful or interesting but would like to be shown otherwise

Answer (score 4):

You can use it for dynamic programming. The example that comes to mind is the [Smith-Waterman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

data Base = T | C | A | G deriving (Eq,Show)
data Diff = Sub Base Base | Id Base | Del Base | Ins Base deriving (Eq,Show)

loeb x = let go = fmap ($ go) x in go

s a b = if a == b then 1 else 0

smithWaterman a' b' = let
  [al,bl] = map length [a',b']
  [a,b] = zipWith (\l s -> array (1,s) $ zip [1..] l) [a',b'] [al,bl]
  h = loeb $ array ((0,0),(al,bl)) $
    [((x,0),const 0) | x <- [0 .. al]] ++
    [((0,y),const 0) | y <- [1 .. bl]] ++
    [((x,y),\h' -> maximum [
       0,
       (h' ! (x - 1,y - 1)) + s (a ! x) (b ! y),
       (h' ! (x - 1, y)) + 1,
       (h' ! (x, y - 1)) + 1
      ]
     ) | x <- [1 .. al], y <- [1 .. bl]]
  ml l (0,0) = l
  ml l (x,0) = ml (Del (a ! x): l) (x - 1, 0)
  ml l (0,y) = ml (Ins (b ! y): l) (0, y - 1)
  ml l (x,y) = let
    (p,e) = maximumBy ((`ap` snd) . (. fst) . (const .) . (. (h !)) . compare . (h !) . fst) [
      ((x - 1,y),Del (a ! x)),
      ((y, x - 1),Ins (b ! y)),
      ((y - 1, x - 1),if a ! x == b ! y then Id (a ! x) else Sub (a ! x) (b ! y))
     ]
    in ml (e : l) p
  in ml [] (al,bl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a live example where it is used for:  Map String Float

http://tryplayg.herokuapp.com/try/spreadsheet.hs/edit

with loop detection and loop resolution.

This program calculates speed, time and space. Each one depends on the other two. Each cell has two values: his current entered value and the expression as a function of the other cell values/expressions.  circularity is permitted.

The Cell recalculation code uses the famous loeb expression by Dan Piponi in the 2006. Until now by my knowledge there haven't been any materialization of this formula on a real working spreadsheet. this one is close to it. Since loeb enters in a infinite loop when circular expressions are used, the program counts the loops and reduces complexity by progressively substituting formulas by cell values until the expression has no loops

This program is configured for immediate recalculation on cell change, but that can be adapted to allow the modification of more than one cell before recalculation by triggering it by means of a button.

This is blog pos:

http://haskell-web.blogspot.com.es/2014/09/spreadsheet-like-program-in-browser.html